# IE11 : cross iframe file handling

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I want to pass javascript File object from one iframe to another. The file is selected by the user with a dialogue box. 
I pass the file using the following code in the destination iframe :

```
var file_selection_field = top.frames['sourceIframe'].document.getElementById('FileSelectionFieldId');
var the_file = file_selection_field.files[0];
```

Then I slice the file and upload it to the server using AJAX.

```
the file.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
// Ajax call ..
```

The problem is that once my source iframe is changed (and the file is still loaded in the destination iframe) I get "Script70:permission denied" error in IE11 when I call the slice function.

Both iframes are at the same domain.

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: How is the source iframe "changed"?

Comment: My application has a menu with which I browse different pages, all pages are presented in the said source iframe, so when I browse the menu, the page is changed. The page in question is the "download" page.

Comment: _Both iframes are at the same domain._ Just to be clear, is this the same domain as your main page that contains the iframes?

Comment: Yes, it's a single application, the main layout is divided into iframes. The iframe which commits the AJAX call for the file upload is a side-iframe and is fixed on the page. I placed the AJAX call there to allow navigation through different pages in the main-iframe.

Comment: How do the `<iframe>` elements communicate? Does the code pass a `File` object to `.postMessage()`?

Comment: Nope. I pass the File object as I demonstrated above. I don't use postMessage. Is it possible to pass a File object with the postMessage function?

Comment: How does the code at Question pass a `File` object from one `iframe` to a separate `iframe`? Presently an `ArrayBuffer` is expected as a transferable object. Can you reproduce the issue at plnkr http://plnkr.co? Note, am not able to verify reproduction of issue at ie

Comment: As I showed above. In the destination iframe, the one which calls the AJAX, I got the following code in <script> tag : top.frames['sourceIframe'].document.getElementById('FileSelectionFieldId'); I get the file from here.